# check if JS object exists

Tags: javascript

I need to discover at runtime if an object with a given name exists, but this name is stored in a variable as a string.

For example, in my Javascript I have an object named test, then at runtime I write the word "text" in a box, and I store this string in a variable, let's name it input. How can I check if a variable named with the string stored in input variable exist?

Comment: `typeof window["string"] === "object"`

Comment: I would add a `&& window["string"] !== null` to that to circumvent the typeof null being object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the object is in the global scope;

`var exists = (typeof window["test"] !== "undefined");`

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a browser (i.e. not Node):

```
var varName = 'myVar';
if (typeof(window[varName]) == 'undefined') {
  console.log("Variable " + varName + " not defined");
} else {
  console.log("Variable " + varName + " defined");
}
```

However, let me say that I would find it *very* hard to justify writing this code in a project. You should know what variables you have, unless you expect people to write plugins to your code or something.

Answer (score 1):

```
if( window[input])...
```

All global variables are properties of the `window` object. `[]` notation allows you to get them by an expression.

Comment: Will give incorrect result for variables that are defined but have falsy values.

Comment: @Amadan Since we're testing for objects, and no object (not even an empty one) has a falsy value, this is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Oh, missed the part about it having to be an object.

Comment: No problem, it's fair enough. Strictly speaking it should be checking its type against undefined, but this is a case of circumstances altering requirements.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see whether it exists as a global variable, you can check for a member variable on the window object. window is the global object, so its members are globals.

```
if (typeof window['my_objname_str'] != 'undefined')
{
    // my_objname_str is defined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing my code but not allways can know if a method exists. I load my js files depending on requests. Also I have methods to bind objects "via" ajax responses and need to know, if they must  call the default callbacks or werther or not particular a method is available.
So a test like :

```
function doesItExist(oName){ 
   var e = (typeof window[oName] !== "undefined"); 
   return e;
}
```

is suitable for me.